# Not able to use xsl:if to control display of <tr> tag

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to create a custom sharepoint web page using xsl.  In this web page, I need to display a list with two records per row.  Below is the code I came up with.  But when I try to access the page, the page fail to display.  It works only if  I remove the  code that it uses to control display of  tag.  Any reason why this if condition is causing the page to fail?

```
<xsl:template match="/" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" />
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
            <xsl:call-template name="menu.rowview" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="menu.rowview">
<!-- two record per table row -->
<xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1" >   
<tr>
</xsl:if>   
    <td>
        <span><xsl:value-of select="@MenuDesc" /></span>
    </td>

<!-- two record per table row -->
<xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1" >   
</tr>   
</xsl:if>   

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your xslt isn't a well formed XML, please correct it.. that's the reason it's not showing up. <tr> starts in an <xsl:if> and ends(</tr>) in some other <xsl:if>. That shouldn't be the case, both start and end tags of an element should fall under only one parent.

Comment: I'm new to xsl.  I guess that is not allow in xsl protocol.  In that case, I won't be able to use that to show 2 records per row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Lingamurthy CS, XSLT needs to be a well-formed XML document, and yours currently isn't because of lines like this...

```
<xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1" >   
<tr>
</xsl:if>
```

What you are trying to do with your XSLT is a fairly common issue. The approach you need to take is to start off by only selecting the **Row** elements that are the start of each "row" you wish to output:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$Rows[position() mod 2 = 1]">
```

Then, you could output both "cells" by outputting the current **Row** and the following one

```
        <tr>
           <td>
              <span>
                 <xsl:value-of select="@MenuDesc"/>
              </span>
           </td>
           <td>
              <span>
                 <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Row[1]/@MenuDesc"/>
              </span>
           </td>
        </tr>
```

Of course, there is a little bit of code repetition here, so you could make better use of templates to re-use. Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>
      <table>
         <xsl:for-each select="$Rows[position() mod 2 = 1]">
            <tr>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::Row[1]"/>
            </tr>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Row">
      <td>
         <span>
            <xsl:value-of select="@MenuDesc"/>
         </span>
      </td>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You would probably need to amend this to cope with an odd number of cells (and so only one cell in the final row), either by adding a colspan attribute to the final cell, or an empty cell.

Comment: Thank you.  I used your apply-templates method and it works perfectly.